# How to deal with a two-way @DBref in Spring Data?

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data, dbref

I have a Bike model:

```
public class Bike {

    @Id
    private ObjectId objectId;

    @DBRef
    private Brand brand;

    private String model;
}
```

and a Brand model:

```
public class Brand {

    @Id
    private ObjectId objectId;

    private String name;

    @DBRef
    private List<Bike> bikes;
}
```

If I use the `bikeRepository.findAll()` provided by Spring Data, I get into a loop, since bikes makes reference to Brand document, which in turns has references to Bike document.

How to deal with this? I would like to get the bike list with the brand object (or even just the brand name)

Answer (score 0):

Try to add an `@JsonBackReference` annotation to your bike class:

```
public class Bike {

    @Id
    private ObjectId objectId;

    @JsonBackReference
    @DBRef
    private Brand brand;

    private String model;
}
```

Comment: I tried this, and even though that makes the query work a bit faster, it is still extremely slow. When I had a String as a brand instead of a Brand object the query executed in less than 2 seconds. Now, with the same amount of bikes, it takes somewhere between 12 and 15 seconds

Comment: @SebastianM Well your original question only asked about the loop problem. How do you keep your documents on MongoDB?

Comment: What do you mean with how?

Comment: @SebastianM As in do you hold ObjectId 's of bikes in Brand? And the objectID of brand in bike?

Comment: Yes, that is how I keep my documents. I pasted my code in the original post for reference.